# I want to create the simplest python socket server for chatting on AWS EC2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

Server code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 81))
client = []
print('Start Server')
while 1:
    data, addres = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(addres[0], addres[1])
    if addres not in client:
        client.append(addres)
    for clients in client:
        sock.sendto(data, clients)
```

Client code:

```
import socket
import threading
def read_sok():
     while 1 :
         data = sor.recv(1024)
         print(data.decode('utf-8'))
server = '54.236.40.62', 81 # Public IP
alias = input()
sor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sor.bind(('', 0))
sor.sendto((alias+' Connect to server').encode('utf-8'), server)
potok = threading.Thread(target= read_sok)
potok.start()
while 1 :
    mensahe = input()
    sor.sendto(('['+alias+']'+mensahe).encode('utf-8'), server)
```

The server OS is the linux ubuntu(third in quick start).
Python 3.10.6 is on the server. 3.11.1 on the client.
The server must resend incoming message to everyone clients, which have ever sent messages to it(including the client, who sent this message). When everything is ok, the client sends a message to the server and receives it back.
The problem is that the client(on my PC) can't interact with the sever. It just can't see the server. The client sends the message to the server and does not receive the message(the same situation when the server is turned off or the IP is incorrect for it).

---

1)These codes work fine if they are on the same PC or on the same network.
2)I didn't forget about security group settings. Port 81 is opened as 80. I started apache2 default page through 80 and it works well in the browser. I also tried using port 80(which certainly works well) for python server(unsuccessful).
3) I know that I can't use public IP for sock.bind(('', 81)). I tried using both sock.bind(('', 81)) and sock.bind(('Private_IP', 81)) cases.
4) I also used ports like 12345 and etc.

I would be grateful for any advice:)

Comment: You haven't even specified what OS on EC2 you are using. What are the actual errors you get? What python version do you use?

Comment: I just added the details you asked about.